# OleDBDataAdapter Fill error Select statement using VB.net and MS access

Tags: vb.net

Help, My code fails on da.fill(dt). The error says OleDBexception was unhandled 
no value given for one or more required parameter

My code

```
        Dim Conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim connString As String
        Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim oCmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim SQLString As String

        connString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source =" & sRemoteAccessFolder & "Projects.MDB"
        Conn.ConnectionString = connString
        Conn.Open()
        SQLString = "select * from tblProjects where ProjectNumber='10100'"


        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLString, Conn)
        da.Fill(dt)
```

Any idea?

thx u

Comment: What happen if you run the query without where clause?

Comment: I missed that it failse on da.fill

Comment: @T.S. if this was the case then the Conn.Open would fail, but the error message will be very different

Comment: Solved.. The problem caused by incorrect t-sql syntax! .. I fix the SQL string and now it is working! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line has problems probably:

```
SQLString = "select * from tblProjects where ProjectNumber='10100'"
```

The field ProjectNumber has to match what is in the table.  If there is a space, then you need to include brackets:

```
SQLString = "select * from tblProjects where [Project Number]='10100'"
```

If it's a numeric field, then drop the quotes:

```
SQLString = "select * from tblProjects where [Project Number]=10100"
```

If you still have errors, then make sure you have a table called tblProjects in the database.

As always, make sure to use Parameters instead of doing the sql statement completely by hand.  That will avoid potential sql injection issues.

Comment: You are correct sir. I made a mistake on the SQL query. the correct string is select * from tblProjects where [ProjectID] = '10100'

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it for long time. But may be do as follow.

```
  connString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source =" & sRemoteAccessFolder &  "Projects.MDB"
  Conn.ConnectionString = connString
  Conn.Open()

  Dim oCmd As new OleDb.OleDbCommand
  oCmd.CommandText= "select ...."
  Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
  Dim dt As New DataTable

  da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(oCmd)
  da.Fill(dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened in my project as well.

```
SQLString = "select * from tblProjects where ProjectNumber='10100'"
```

I followed the same and concluded this way it helped me. The correct statement which worked for me is

```
SQLString = "select * from tblProjects where [ProjectNumber]='10100'"
```

Comment: Brackets would only be needed if the column had a space in it or matches a keyword, like [Date].  Numbers shouldn't be strings.  Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.